# How do I configure the touchscreen on an HP x360?

Tags: laptop, configuration, touchscreen

I just got this laptop today, and my first action was to install the latest version of Ubuntu to mess around with. Is there any way to reinstate the convertible functions of the laptop, or at least the touchscreen aspect? If not I might end up switching back to windows and then running Ubuntu in a virtual box since I already have a desktop PC running Ubuntu if I desperately need something.